# How can I convert an XPS format document to PDF?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-office, printing, xps, xps-viewer

Sometimes when I print from Firefox, if the printer is not available, I select the printer as **Microsoft XPS Document Wiewer**, which allows me to save the document in XPS format to my PC.
There are a lot of online services that claim to convert XPS files to PDF, but that isn't an option as the document often contains personal information.

Is there any way to convert an XPS file to PDF locally?

Note: I would prefer not to install extra software only for this purpose, a way to do this natively or with commonly available software like Microsoft Office Suit or with the Microsoft XPS Viewer itself is much preferable.

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: what version of windows? 10 has native PDF printing

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Windows 7

Comment: What version of Office? Some newer ones do PDF natively. Windows 7 on the other hand has no native PDF support at all.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Office 2007. But I have the conver to pdf add-on installed.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 7 you will have to install additional software (unless you also have a recent version of Office, see below).
Any of the free PDF printer utilities will do.
Just open the XPS in XPS viewer and print to the PDF printer-driver. And in the future print directly to the PDF printer-driver instead of to XPS.

In case you have Office 2013, 2016 or Office 365 MS-Word can save a document directly to PDF. In that case simply make a new Word document. Load the XPS in XPS Viewer. Then Copy/Paste the XPS content into Word.

Comment: Can't I use the XPS viewer itself to convert?

Comment: Since there's an option to *Save As** option in XPS viewer.

Comment: @RogUE All options available in "Save As" are part of the program itself (XPS Viewer in this case). There is no way to add something extra into that, even if you have other software on the computer that happens to have particular functionality. (There is an exception to that. Some software can receive an extension to supported Save As formats in the form of a plugin module. XPS Viewer isn't one of those programs.)

Comment: 'Save as' doesn't show any other formats, but it does show 'All files'.

Answer (score 0):

You can get GhostXPS from here:

https://ghostscript.com/download/gxpsdnld.html

Then convert like this:

```
gxpswin64 -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=a.pdf a.xps
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mutool`.

```bash
mutool convert -o out.pdf in.xps
```